# Jquery long paragraph show more/show less link not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to code this and the "read more" link is working fine but "show less" link is not. I am unable to detect the error.
Here in this code there is an anchor tag with `class="show-less"` using which i am trying to hide span element with `class="spanTxt"` but something is wrong and its not hiding span element.
I am not getting it, if i can do `display:inline` in read more link then why it's not working when i do `display:none` in show less link.

Thanks in advance :)

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>jQuery Add Read More Link</title>
    <script type="text/javascript"   src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var maxLength = 300;
        $(".show-read-more").each(function(){
            var myStr = $(this).text();
            if($.trim(myStr).length > maxLength){
                var newStr = myStr.substring(0, maxLength);
                var removedStr = myStr.substring(maxLength, $.trim(myStr).length);

                $(this).replaceWith('<p class="show-read-more">'+newStr+'<a class="read-more" href="#">read more...</a>'+'<span id="hoja" class="spanTxt" style="display:none">'+removedStr+'</span>'+'</p>');
            }
        });
        $(".read-more").click(function(){
            $(".spanTxt").css("display","inline");
            $(".show-read-more").append('<a href="#" class="show-less">show   less...</a>');
            $(this).hide();
        });



    $(".show-less").click(function(){
            $(".spanTxt").css("display","none");


        });
    });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
          <p class="show-read-more">Ut auctor velit sed consectetur rhoncus. Nunc 
            dictum facilisis felis nec facilisis. Integer nec justo vitae orci cursus 
            fermentum. Fusce semper, mi non tempus congue, velit leo efficitur quam, 
            laoreet venenatis libero felis et lacus. Pellentesque mattis hendrerit 
            nisi gravida hendrerit. Mauris sagittis tincidunt scelerisque. Vivamus lectus 
            erat, dictum et magna quis, iaculis finibus nisl. Aliquam quis ante odio. Eti
            am tincidunt tellus tristique turpis tincidunt, eget condimentum urna rutrum. 
            Donec maximus consequat dolor, sit amet condimentum ipsum gravida ac. Etiam p
            osuere tellus mauris, et dignissim nisl rutrum quis. Mauris tincidunt ante 
            sed velit maximus, vel tincidunt leo imperdiet. Morbi nec lac
            us et metus semper porttitor. Sed pellentesque ex at 
            pellentesque scelerisque. Aliquam placerat gravida tortor, in fermentum ante
            commodo quis. Etiam vehicula elementum quam. Aliquam eu augue eu lacus digni
            ssim efficitur. Proin ex metus, ornare placerat nisi at, porta lobortis turpi
            s. Praesent euismod nec nulla ultrices maximus. Vivamus imperdiet quam ac
            lobortis cursus. Nam dapibus ullamcorper magna vehicula aliquam. Vivamus 
            hendrerit molestie neque. Ut interdum diam a purus ultrices facilisis. 
            Suspendisse molestie tempor dolor, sed tristique enim sagittis vitae. I
            nteger eu dignissim lectus, commodo eff
            icitur metus. Morbi quis justo finibus, interdum sem quis, imperdiet tellus
            andit vel magna nec elementum. Vivamus tempor, urna pharetra euismod euis
            mod, elit elit tincidunt sem, ut consectetur arcu massa non diam.
            Etiam scelerisque nisi magna. Nulla facilisi. 
            Sed pharetra nunc lectus, in maximus dolor ornare sit amet.</p>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got several issues there (some caused the code not to work, some caused the work to work but only for the first `p.show-read-more` element.

Here is the fix:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var maxLength = 300;
  $(".show-read-more").each(function(){
    var myStr = $(this).text();
    if ($.trim(myStr).length > maxLength) {
      var newStr = myStr.substring(0, maxLength);
      var removedStr = myStr.substring(maxLength, $.trim(myStr).length);
      var newP = $('<p class="show-read-more">'+newStr+'<a class="read-more" href="#">read more...</a>'+'<span id="hoja" class="spanTxt" style="display:none">'+removedStr+'</span>'+'</p>')
      newP.append($('<a href="#" class="show-less">show   less...</a>').hide())
      $(this).replaceWith(newP);
    }
  });
  $(".read-more").click(function(){
    $(this).parent('.show-read-more').find('.spanTxt').css("display","inline");
    $(this).parent('.show-read-more').find('.show-less').show();
    $(this).hide();
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.show-less', function(){
    $(this).parent('.show-read-more').find('.read-more').show();
    $(this).parent('.show-read-more').find(".spanTxt").hide();
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript"   src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="show-read-more">Ut auctor velit sed consectetur rhoncus. Nunc 
  dictum facilisis felis nec facilisis. Integer nec justo vitae orci cursus 
  fermentum. Fusce semper, mi non tempus congue, velit leo efficitur quam, 
  laoreet venenatis libero felis et lacus. Pellentesque mattis hendrerit 
  nisi gravida hendrerit. Mauris sagittis tincidunt scelerisque. Vivamus lectus 
  erat, dictum et magna quis, iaculis finibus nisl. Aliquam quis ante odio. Eti
  am tincidunt tellus tristique turpis tincidunt, eget condimentum urna rutrum. 
  Donec maximus consequat dolor, sit amet condimentum ipsum gravida ac. Etiam p
  osuere tellus mauris, et dignissim nisl rutrum quis. Mauris tincidunt ante 
  sed velit maximus, vel tincidunt leo imperdiet. Morbi nec lac
  us et metus semper porttitor. Sed pellentesque ex at 
  pellentesque scelerisque. Aliquam placerat gravida tortor, in fermentum ante
  commodo quis. Etiam vehicula elementum quam. Aliquam eu augue eu lacus digni
  ssim efficitur. Proin ex metus, ornare placerat nisi at, porta lobortis turpi
  s. Praesent euismod nec nulla ultrices maximus. Vivamus imperdiet quam ac
  lobortis cursus. Nam dapibus ullamcorper magna vehicula aliquam. Vivamus 
  hendrerit molestie neque. Ut interdum diam a purus ultrices facilisis. 
  Suspendisse molestie tempor dolor, sed tristique enim sagittis vitae. I
  nteger eu dignissim lectus, commodo eff
  icitur metus. Morbi quis justo finibus, interdum sem quis, imperdiet tellus
  andit vel magna nec elementum. Vivamus tempor, urna pharetra euismod euis
  mod, elit elit tincidunt sem, ut consectetur arcu massa non diam.
  Etiam scelerisque nisi magna. Nulla facilisi. 
  Sed pharetra nunc lectus, in maximus dolor ornare sit amet.</p>
<p class="show-read-more">Ut auctor velit sed consectetur rhoncus. Nunc 
  dictum facilisis felis nec facilisis. Integer nec justo vitae orci cursus 
  fermentum. Fusce semper, mi non tempus congue, velit leo efficitur quam, 
  laoreet venenatis libero felis et lacus. Pellentesque mattis hendrerit 
  nisi gravida hendrerit. Mauris sagittis tincidunt scelerisque. Vivamus lectus 
  erat, dictum et magna quis, iaculis finibus nisl. Aliquam quis ante odio. Eti
  am tincidunt tellus tristique turpis tincidunt, eget condimentum urna rutrum. 
  Donec maximus consequat dolor, sit amet condimentum ipsum gravida ac. Etiam p
  osuere tellus mauris, et dignissim nisl rutrum quis. Mauris tincidunt ante 
  sed velit maximus, vel tincidunt leo imperdiet. Morbi nec lac
  us et metus semper porttitor. Sed pellentesque ex at 
  pellentesque scelerisque. Aliquam placerat gravida tortor, in fermentum ante
  commodo quis. Etiam vehicula elementum quam. Aliquam eu augue eu lacus digni
  ssim efficitur. Proin ex metus, ornare placerat nisi at, porta lobortis turpi
  s. Praesent euismod nec nulla ultrices maximus. Vivamus imperdiet quam ac
  lobortis cursus. Nam dapibus ullamcorper magna vehicula aliquam. Vivamus 
  hendrerit molestie neque. Ut interdum diam a purus ultrices facilisis. 
  Suspendisse molestie tempor dolor, sed tristique enim sagittis vitae. I
  nteger eu dignissim lectus, commodo eff
  icitur metus. Morbi quis justo finibus, interdum sem quis, imperdiet tellus
  andit vel magna nec elementum. Vivamus tempor, urna pharetra euismod euis
  mod, elit elit tincidunt sem, ut consectetur arcu massa non diam.
  Etiam scelerisque nisi magna. Nulla facilisi. 
  Sed pharetra nunc lectus, in maximus dolor ornare sit amet.</p>
```

Comment: Thanx for the awesome solution. But it is still not satisfactory to me for not getting to know where i went wrong..

Answer (score -1):

You have not added an ending for `$(document).ready(function(){`, in the end of your script. Else the javascript will throw errors.

Comment: He does, and even if not - this is not what will solve the problem.